# What does "in-horse" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "in-horse" mean as in this sentence?

> To contact the fire and Rescue Department immediately, activate **in-horse** fire squad for fire fighting (while waiting for BOMBA) and safety evacuation, including visitors from the building.

Apparently there isn't a idiom "in-horse". The only possible meanings of "horse" are the animal "horse" and the vaulting horse, neither of which make sense to me.

Comment: This looks like a typo for "[in-house](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/in-house)" Could you provide a link to the source?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be a simple spelling mistake.  No useful answer is possible

Comment: @James K. Here is the context: http://www.specialskill.com.my/main/3141/index.asp?pageid=179516&t=standard-operational-procedure-for-security-personnel. Thank you. I would have never thought it was a typo.

Comment: Yes, certainly a spelling mistake. The source contains other errors and non-idiomatic usage, eg "at all time" instead of the idiomatic "at all times"

Comment: @Ummi - "I would have never thought it was a typo" - really? You think 'in-horse' might be a real thing?

Comment: @JamesK "All security personnel are not allowed to lean against a wall or appear sleepy while at their respective posts of duty.". This is not normal English. Likewise: "All security personnel are not allowed to sit or chit-chat in any of the shops or offices in the building.". Reads like Inglish from someone who has been told to prepare a list of rules and decided to concoct as many as possible.

Comment: It reads like notes quickly typed at a meeting rather than an official document